# Importing data from excel to SSMS 2016 via SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

The data in the excel file starts from 5th row and I have date in the F16 column, first row.

The data in F16 column is of type Float.

When I try to import the data(uncheck first row as header in excel connection manager) it gives me an error
"Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

I believe this is because of data type mismatch(date and float in same column)

Is there a way I can get the date as well as the data?  I am new to SSIS. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use OpenRowset or Query Excel Sheet to get data from excel from specific lines  .

[Nice article on mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4150/how-to-read-data-from-an-excel-file-starting-from-the-nth-row-with-sql-server-integration-services/);